# Jquery count number of rows in the table not working

Tags: jquery

I'm adding dynamically rows to a table, I have a "remove row" button to remove current row from the table. It's working correctly except I want to leave at least on row in the table. To do that, I added a test to get the current number of rows inside the table but it always return 1, it's like the value is not updated, why not ?

Here is the table :

```
<table id="fla_inf" width="100%">
<tr>
<th class="tab_header" colspan="6">Flavors and Additives</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Brand</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Name</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Dropper Type</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Quantity</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Total %</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Add/Remove row</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
     <td><select id="marque.0" name="marque,0"></select></td>
     <td><select id="arome.0" name="arome.0"></select></td>
     <td><select id="dropper.0" name="dropper.0"></select></td>
     <td><input id="quantity.0" name="quantity.0" type="number"/></td>
     <td><input id="fla_perc.0" name="fla_perc.0" type="number" min="0" max="100"/></td>
     <td><input class="addline" type="image" src="http://spitilab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/add.png"><input class="remline" type="image" src="http://spitilab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/delete.png"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here is the remove part of the code :

```
// Remove row from the table
$(document).on('click', '.remline', function() {
    alert($('#fla_inf').length);
    if ($('#fla_inf').length > 1) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the length of tr elements:

```
$('#fla_inf tr').length;
```

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.remline', function() {
alert($('#fla_inf tr').length);
if ($('#fla_inf tr').length > 1) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always keep one row in the table body, excluding the rows in the header(you have 2 rows), you can use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remline', function() { 
  alert($('#fla_inf tbody tr').length);  
  if ($('#fla_inf tbody tr').length > 1) {  
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();  
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I start to understand better how to filter to specific elements.